# Executing sudo in a script using expect works but then dropped out

Tags: sudo, expect

I have a script like below that basically auto execute "sudo -i", entered password and become root. Problem was that once I become root, it just froze about 10 seconds and then got dropped out back to regular user.

I checked in the /var/log/auth and /var/log/syslog, there is no error.
I wonder whats wrong. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
    spawn sudo -i
    expect "*?assword*"
    send -- "mypassword\r"
    expect eof
```

Comment: If you want to *do stuff* once you get the root shell, you likely need an `interact` in there

Comment: Is it the only function of the script or is it embedded in a bigger script?

Comment: Thanks guys, it works perfectly now.